# Indefinite time for Reduce a set of conditions

Tags: equation-solving, condition

Following command is taking too ling time to run.

```
Reduce[Abs[b2 + b0] < 1 + b1 && Abs[b2 - 3 b0] < 3 - b1 && (b0^2 + b1
- b0 b2) < 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && m > 0, {a, b, m}, Reals]
```

Where,

```
b0 = -((2 a (1 + a^2 m^2 - Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)] - 
      a (1 + 8 b) m (-2 + Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)])))/(b m^2)

b1 = (-1 + Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)] + 
  a m (3 + 4 a m - 4 Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)] + 
     2 b (-7 + 16 a m + 3 Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)])))/(2 b m^2)

b2 = (-1 + 3 a m + Sqrt[1 + a m (2 + 16 b + a m)])/m
```

Any help is solicited.

Comment: Even `ClearAll[b0, b1, b2];LeafCount[
 Reduce[RealAbs[b2 + b0] < 1 + b1 && 
    RealAbs[b2 - 3 b0] < 3 - b1 && (b0^2 + b1 - b0 b2) < 1, {b1, b0, 
    b2}, Reals] // FullSimplify]` performs `342`.

Comment: Nothing comes useful